# How to decompose as partial fraction?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-functions

Let $t\in \mathbb R, n\in \mathbb N.$

> How should I choose $A, B$ and $C$ so
>
> $$\frac{(t-n)^2t^2}{[1+(t-n)^2)]^3} = \frac{A}{[1+(t-n)^2)]^3}+  \frac{B}{[1+(t-n)^2)]^2} +  \frac{C}{[1+(t-n)^2)]}$$

**My Try:**

We may rewrite, $$t^{4}-2nt^3+n^2t^2= A+ B(n^2-2nt+t^2+1)^2 + C (n^2-2nt+t^2+1)$$

If we take $t=0,$ we have  $$0=A+B(n^2+1)^2 + C(n^2+1)$$

If we take $t=n,$ then we have $$0=A+B+C$$

If we take $t=1,$ we have $$(1-n)^2=A+ B(1+ (1-n)^2)^2 + C  (1+ (1-n)^2)$$

But I am struggling  to decide $A, B, C$ from these informations...

Answer (score 2):

HINT : Change of variable $x=t-n$
$$\frac{(t-n)^2t^2}{(1+(t-n)^2)^3}=\frac{x^2(x+n)^2}{(1+x^2)^3}=n^2\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^3}+2n\frac{x^3}{(1+x^2)^3}+\frac{x^4}{(1+x^2)^3}$$
isn't it easier now to decompose each of the three terms ?